# Sql developer: How to show ID and name of either student or course?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In this exercise from my homework, I have to, using a single query, show either the student id or the course id labeled "Id" and either the name of the student or the name of the course labeled as "Student or course" related to the professor named "Brown".
I don't know how to implement this condition in select to have the query show either one of the two based on a condition.

Students have the external prof_id , and professors have the external course_id.

I can only come up with a four column showing Id twice and "Student or course" twice.

I tried using Case or the "with" - "as" clause but did not seem to work

My current query is:

```sql
    SELECT s_id AS "Id", s_name AS "Student or course",
           r.course_no AS "Id", course_name AS "Student or course"
    FROM students JOIN professors f ON ( f.prof_id LIKE prof_id)
    JOIN course c ON (c.prof_id = f.prof_id) 
    WHERE f.f_name LIKE 'Brown';
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
    select to_char(s_id) "Cod", s_last "Student sau curs",
        'Student' "Tip"
    from student join faculty using(f_id)
    where lower (f_last) = 'brown'

    union

    select to_char(c_sec_id), course_name, 'Curs'
    from faculty join course_section using (f_id)
         join course using (course_no)
    where lower (f_last) = 'brown';
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.